# GraphDB + Lucene Index: can I get the matched predicate / literal?

Tags: lucene, graphdb

Following [the instructions](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/full-text-search.html) i set up an index that covers multiple (literal-)predicates:

```
  PREFIX luc: <http://www.ontotext.com/owlim/lucene#>
  INSERT DATA {
    luc:index             luc:setParam "uris" .
    luc:include           luc:setParam "literals" .
    luc:moleculeSize      luc:setParam "1" .
    luc:includePredicates luc:setParam "http://purl.org/dc/terms/title http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#altLabel" .
  }
```

and

```
PREFIX luc: <http://www.ontotext.com/owlim/lucene#>
INSERT DATA {
  luc:${Cfg.literalIndex}   luc:createIndex   "true" .
}
```

This part seems to work just fine. My question now is, **is there some way to get the matched predicate or literal in my SPARQL query**?

So assume the following data:

```
:exA rdfs:label     'label' ;
     dct:title      'title' .
```

I'd like to do something like this

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?needle luc:labelIndex "title" ;
          luc:predicate  ?predicate ;
          ?predicate     ?label .
}
```

If something like this `luc:predicate` exists, this could give me the actually matched predicate alongside the matches value. However, I'm not even sure Lucene indexes the predicate, which would be needed to enable such a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this efficiently with the legacy FTS Lucene plugin. However, the [Lucene Connectors](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/lucene-graphdb-connector.html) easily supports your use case. Here is a sample case with some mock data:

**Sample data**

```
<urn:a> a <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept> ;
    <http://purl.org/dc/terms/title> "title"; 
    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "label" ; 
    <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel> "prefer label"; 
    <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#altLabel> "alt label" .
```

Note: Connectors index the data for a single `rdf:type`. In your example, I believe you should have `skos:Concept`.

**Create Lucene Connector**

Connectors will index for the selected type every property or a property chain into a separate Lucene field.

```
PREFIX : <http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/lucene#>
PREFIX inst: <http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/lucene/instance#>

INSERT DATA {
    inst:fts :createConnector '''
{
  "types": [
    "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept"
  ],
  "fields": [
    {
      "fieldName": "label",
      "propertyChain": [
        "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label"
      ]
    },
    {
      "fieldName": "prefLabel",
      "propertyChain": [
        "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel"
      ]
    },
    {
      "fieldName": "altLabel",
      "propertyChain": [
        "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#altLabel"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
''' .
}
```

**Return the matching fields and snippet**

```
PREFIX : <http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/lucene#>
PREFIX inst: <http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/lucene/instance#>
SELECT ?entity ?snippetField ?snippetText {
    ?search a inst:fts ;
            :query "label" ;
            :entities ?entity .
    ?entity :snippets _:s .
    _:s :snippetField ?snippetField ;
        :snippetText ?snippetText .
}
```

Where in the projection:

- ?entities is the RDF resource for which a property or a property chain matched i.e.
- ?snippetField is the field name matching the full-text query
- ?snippetText is the matched snippet value